# Is there a way to create a scannable barcode that links to your app on marketplace?

Tags: android, google-play, qr-code

I am trying to find a way that allows you to scan one of those online barcodes and have it link up to my droid app - anyone have any idea how to get one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can simply use any kind of QR code generator to generate a link to your applications market presence.

The QR Code below was created using [ZXing's Online QR Code Generator](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/)

[image]

This QR Code links to a pseudo app with following link.

`market://details?id=com.example.my.cool.app`

Scanning this code using a QR Code scanner app will open the market on your device linking you to your application.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  Where can I find the URL to my app when I receive it?  On the publishing site?

Comment: @Sapp: Your URL consists of your package name. Look at the example above. `com.example.my.cool.app`. Now just substitute that with your package name.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the uncountable meta market site like http://www.androidpit.com/

Search for your application there and you will find a QR code for the market link there, too.

[edit] Afaik the update of the page is at least once a day, so you should see your new app soon there. As your link doesn't change on update you don't need to change the QR code [/edit]